# 'makes' or 'make' for this sentence

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> What are the elements in the poem that make it joyful.

or

> What are the elements in the poem that makes it joyful.

Answer (score 6):

The subject of *make* is the plural *elements*, whether you regard *that* as a relative pronoun or whether, like some grammarians, you don't. It follows that the verb must be plural, so *make*.

Answer (score 0):

The first one. The second one could be correct if you wrote it as:

> What is the element in the poem that makes it joyful?

Or more simply:

> What element in the poem makes it joyful?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably choose *which* instead of *what*, because you have a finite set of elements to choose from.

> Which are the elements in the poem that make it joyful?

That being said, *make* should be used as the plural verb for *elements*, which is referred to by *that*.

> The elements (that make me joyful) are [which].

**RESOURCES**

- http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00052.htm